# Format Date from Offset to Greenwich to standard time in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time, format

I am currently looking at some data I uploaded from the EPA website but the date is formatted a little funny: 20170101T2300-0500
I tried reformatting the date and time at once which did not work so I split the column by "T" and successfully reformatted the date but when I entered

```
Df$time<-strptime(as.character(Df$time),"%I%M%z")
Df$time<- format(Df$time, "%I:%M:%S")
```

The time column turned into N/A's. I read that "z" was the "offset to Greenwich" factor but for output only, I'm unsure if I used it in the correct context.

Answer (score 1):

You can do directly

```
strptime("20170101T2300-0500", "%Y%m%dT%H%M%z")
[1] "2017-01-01 22:00:00"
```

- %Y - Year
- %m - Month
- %d - day
- T - strict text delimiter
- %H - Hours
- %M - Minutes
- %z - signed offset

Comment: @seaparty450, does this answer your question? If so, please, consider [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.